# Sencha Store Load() Couldnt Work

Tags: javascript, extjs

i tried load data from url. 
i have the 2 web page. this pages returning json data. and this pages are returs same data.

its my first page connection. its working requesting data not have problem.

```
    var store =Ext.getStore('strUrunler');
store.setProxy({url:'http://localhost:1002/ZULU/NewMobile/data.aspx?act=getAllProducts'});
store.getProxy();
store.load();
store.sync();
```

and its my second page.

```
 var store =Ext.getStore('strUrunler');
store.setProxy({url:'http://localhost:63195/default.aspx'});
store.getProxy();
store.load();
store.sync();
```

so i just changed proxy url. but its not working. 2.url requesting data from page but showing nothing. im looking the chorme console , dont have any error.

my pages source code in here.

http://postimg.org/image/kx5i78p5p/

http://postimg.org/image/kuv52u4nb/

Comment: I notice that your ports are different, you may be encountering a cross origin issue.